# redux-persist - how to whitelist nested state field?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I want to save in storage one full reducer, and only one field from other reducer. How can I do this? I found e.g. [this gh issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/277), but all attempts (from gh link and other sources) turned out to be a failure.

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fermi-obs1g?file=/src/index.js)

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["first"],
  transforms: [createWhitelistFilter("second", ["counter"])]
};
```

It works for `first` reducer, nothing happens with the second, when I want to storage only `counter` field from reducer.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hey do you want to persist both first and second counter values ? i.e on refresh you need both of them to have the values that was saved ?

Comment: I want to save in storage only one field from specific reducer, but not whole reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the issue, I have written a custom transformer to save the counter field for the second reducer. And avoid saving the whole object.

I have used a custom transformer to achieve the functionality. You can read more about this over [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#transforms)

**Solution**

```
const whiteList = createTransform(
  (inboundState, key) => {
    if (key === "second") {
      // This is saving to storage
      // Save only the counter field for second reducer
      return inboundState.counter;
    }
    return inboundState;
  },
  (outBoundState, key) => {
    if (key === "second") {
      // Receiving data from storage
      // add the saved counter field in reducer object
      return {
        name: "",
        counter: outBoundState
      };
    }
    return outBoundState;
  }
);

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  transforms: [whiteList]
};
```

We are only allowing the counter field to save on the storage and while receiving we are adding it to the object value.

Here is the working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-curie-c42rx?file=/src/index.js:416-935).